# Size of Offset for MIPS load word instruction

Tags: mips, mips32

100011 10011 01010 1111111111101100
 OP    base   rt      offset

The above machine code translates to a load word MIPS instruction of 
lw $t2,?($s3)

Can the the offset be 65516, which is the decimal value of the binary offset?
Is there a maximum offset number?

Answer (score 1):

The offset field in the I format instructions is a 16-bit *signed*<sup>1</sup> (2s complement) value, so it can be any value in the range -32768...32767.  In your example, the binary value 1111111111101100 is -20

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's signed for most instructions -- including all the load and store instructions.  It is unsigned for logical instructions (andi/ori/xori) where it is a mask value rather than an offset</sub>